# in node(sails framework) we are getting model name is not defined

Tags: node.js, model, sails.js

In our web app we are getting model name is not defined. In model i have define following properties

```
module.exports ={
 schema:'true',
 autoPK: false,
 autoCreatedAt: false,
 autoUpdatedAt: false,
 tablename : 'outlet_cuisine',
 attributes: {
 outlet_cuisine_id : {type:'int',primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true},
 outlet_id : {type : 'int', model: "outlet"},
 cuisine_id : {type : 'int', model : "cuisine"}
  }
};
```

And in controller i am using following command

Following code for controller:

```
outlet_cuisine.destroy({'outlet_id' : outlet_id},
 function deastrires(err) {

});
```

issue in case sensitive. I am getting outlet_cuisine is not  defined.

Comment: **More info needed**. Do you use waterline? How did you define your Outlet_cuisine? Can you show the code related to defining the model?

Comment: yes, we are using waterline

following code for model 

module.exports = {
schema:'true',
 autoPK: false,
 autoCreatedAt: false,
 autoUpdatedAt: false,
 tablename : 'outlet_cuisine',
  attributes: {
  outlet_cuisine_id : {type:'int',primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true},
  outlet_id : {type : 'int', model: "outlet"},
  cuisine_id : {type : 'int', model : "cuisine"}
  }
};

Comment: That's it? No code? Then read docs https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline and next time read a guide on how to properly ask a question!

Comment: i have updated my question. please check it

Comment: What is name of the file with module.exports in it? I don't use sails.js myself but it looks like if you name the file CuisineOutlet.js the you use it like `CuisineOutlet.find(...)` can you try that?

Comment: my js file name is Outlet_cuisine.js

Comment: So does this `Outlet_cuisine.find(...)` work?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/amangoyal91/krk69/revisions/


please check code on above repo

Comment: You need uppercase O in `Outlet_cuisine.destroy`, **o**utlet_cuisine is wrong